# what is required for a person to do well on imo

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, learning

What kind of skill is required to solve IMO or Putnam sort of problems.
         Does one have to be a genius or 
just learn some tricks.

Comment: "IMO or Putnam sort of problems" doesn't seem to be a valid description. Some of these problems are solvable in required time by ordinary learnable methods, but there are also a few that require more than just diligence.

Comment: I suggest you look at *Solving Mathematical Problems: A Personal Perspective* by Tao, who is an IMO gold medalist.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be a genius, but you do need to know the material inside and out. Being clever doesn't hurt either. But more than tricks you need an understanding of the material. Genius only goes so far. Practice, dedication, motivation... these things are just as important.

Since the scope covers pretty much everything covered in a typical undergrad education, I think it will be difficult to say "you should study A and B". Look at past tests. I know my university had a group which met every week to practice problems, which were then posted online. A quick Google search will give you a lot. That said, they are difficult tests. I was close to a 4.0 student and I only got 1 point on the Putnam.